# sorting names Alphabetical order with Map

Tags: dictionary

I am trying to create a method that gets an arraylist with names and returns a Map (from java) with the names by alphabetical order.
Should I use treeMap and "collection.sort"?

Answer (score 0):

If your input in an `ArrayList<String>` that contains the names you wish to sort, you can sort it with `Collections.sort(yourList)`.

It's not clear how the `ArrayList` of names is related to the `Map` you mentioned. If you have a `Map<String,SomeClass>` where the key is the name you wish to sort by, you can use a `TreeMap`, and the sorting will be taken care of for you:

```
Map<String,SomeClass> sorted = new TreeMap<String,SomeClass>();
```

or if you wish to get a sorted `Map` from an unsorted `Map`:

```
Map<String,SomeClass> sorted = new TreeMap<String,SomeClass>(unsortedMap);
```